# Paper js stops redrawing after loading another script

Tags: javascript, html, paperjs

I'm using paper js to draw an animated set of rectangles. Since there will be several HTML pages in this project, I tried adding the menu HTML programmatically using javascript. However, once the menu script loads, paper js stops redrawing.

I used a timer to delay the loading of the menu script to ascertain if it was any other issue. The animation definitely plays normally right before the menu script loads.

Any other element added programmatically works fine. It's the only paper that stops redrawing.

**HTML**

```
<head>
        <script src="./scripts/paper-full.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/menu.js"></script>
        <script
            type="text/paperscript"
            src="./scripts/paper.js"
            canvas="myCanvas"
        ></script>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css" /> -->
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="main">
            <label id="stats"></label>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**MENU**

```
var label = '<label id="stats"></label>';
var divO = '<div id="menu" class="menu">';
var divC = "</div>";
var html =
    '<a href="./index.html">Home</a> <a href="./projects.html">Projects</a><a href="./blog.html">Blog</a> <a href="./about.html">About</a>';

setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.innerHTML += label + divO + html + divC;
}, 500);
```

**PAPER**

```
var length = 35;

var path = new Path({
    strokeColor: '#E4141B',
    strokeWidth: 20,
    strokeCap: 'round'
});

var start = view.center / [10, 1];
for (var i = 0; i < points; i++)
    path.add(start + new Point(i * length, 0));

function onMouseMove(event) {
    path.firstSegment.point = event.point;
    for (var i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
        var segment = path.segments[i];
        var nextSegment = segment.next;
        var vector = segment.point - nextSegment.point;
        vector.length = length;
        nextSegment.point = segment.point - vector;
    }
    path.smooth({ type: 'continuous' });
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
    path.fullySelected = true;
    path.strokeColor = '#e08285';
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    path.fullySelected = false;
    path.strokeColor = '#e4141b';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are resetting the `document.body.innerHTML` and this somehow breaks `Paper.js` coupling with the canvas.

What I would suggest is using a dedicated element to insert your dynamic content into the DOM, rather that injecting it into the `<body>` directly.

Here is an updated code demonstrating the solution. Have a close look at the lines:

- `<div id="menu-container"></div>`
- `document.querySelector('#menu-container').innerHTML =  label + divO + html + divC;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
    />
</head>
<body id="body">
<div id="main">
    <label id="stats"></label>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</div>
<div id="menu-container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var label = '<label id="stats"></label>';
        var divO = '<div id="menu" class="menu">';
        var divC = "</div>";
        var html =
            '<a href="./index.html">Home</a> <a href="./projects.html">Projects</a><a href="./blog.html">Blog</a> <a href="./about.html">About</a>';
            
        document.querySelector('#menu-container').innerHTML =  label + divO + html + divC;
    </script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
        var length = 35;

        var path = new Path({
            strokeColor: '#E4141B',
            strokeWidth: 20,
            strokeCap: 'round'
        });

        var points = 20

        var start = view.center / [10, 1];
        for (var i = 0; i < points; i++)
            path.add(start + new Point(i * length, 0));

        function onMouseMove(event) {
            path.firstSegment.point = event.point;
            for (var i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
                var segment = path.segments[i];
                var nextSegment = segment.next;
                var vector = segment.point - nextSegment.point;
                vector.length = length;
                nextSegment.point = segment.point - vector;
            }
            path.smooth({ type: 'continuous' });
        }

        function onMouseDown(event) {
            path.fullySelected = true;
            path.strokeColor = '#e08285';
        }

        function onMouseUp(event) {
            path.fullySelected = false;
            path.strokeColor = '#e4141b';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```